# Get image from binary data using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I am using web api to get the image from database, it is returning json data, now the image data which is coming in response is like this

�PNG

���
IHDR��@������   �`���sRGB�������gAMA�����a��� pHYs�������o�d����IDATx^����\�uލ�x����q��N^�q��q��%v��n�H�,Y�7J"A�N��H���{�� :H�$A��wi��g���9w��H�,�u��9s�����yֳ��}��#�Á�1b��9�Ks`���S��1b��9s �@/́�������1b��9�ss �(&}�M�^���5~���9s���
�

how should i convert it back, so that i can see image in my browser , using jquery

current ajax is

```
 $.ajax({
                url:  "/api/v1/images/" + items.image.id + "/w" + items.image.width,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',

                success: function (data) {
                  $('#' + items.id).attr('src',data.responseText);

                },
                error: function (status) {


                }
            });
```

Comment: If you want to stick with a json response containing your data, you should have a look at data URIs ```data:image/png;base64,<base64-encoded-image>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this, it's easier than you think

```
var url = '/api/v1/images/' + items.image.id + '/w' + items.image.width;
$('#' + items.id).attr('src', url);
```

No need for ajax at all.